# How to split an array according to a condition in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

For example, I have a `ndarray` that is:

```
a = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 8])
```

Now I want to split `a` into two parts, one is all numbers <5 and the other is all >=5:

```
[array([1,3,2,4]), array([5,7,6,8])]
```

Certainly I can traverse `a` and create two new array. But I want to know does numpy provide some better ways?

Similarly, for multidimensional array, e.g.

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9],
       [2, 4, 7]])
```

I want to split it according to the first column <3 and >=3, which result is:

```
[array([[1, 2, 3],
        [2, 4, 7]]), 
 array([[4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]])]
```

Are there any better ways instead of traverse it? Thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

def split(arr, cond):
  return [arr[cond], arr[~cond]]

a = np.array([1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8])
print split(a, a<5)

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[2,4,7]])
print split(a, a[:,0]<3)
```

This produces the following output:

```
[array([1, 3, 2, 4]), array([5, 7, 6, 8])]

[array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 7]]), array([[4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])]
```

Comment: Doesn't `arr[cond], arr[~cond]` mean it tests every element of the array for the same condition twice?

Comment: @endolith No. The `a[:,0]<3` will create an array of `bool` with the same dimension as `a`, which says which elements go into the selection. It is just negating the array, which is not expensive.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a quick solution

```
a = np.array([1,3,5,7])
b = a >= 3 # variable with condition
a[b] # to slice the array
len(a[b]) # count the elements in sliced array
```

Answer (score 0):

1d array
**a = numpy.array([2,3,4,...])
a_new = a[(a < 4)] # to get elements less than 5**

2d array based on column(consider value of column i should be less than 5,
**a = numpy.array([[1,2],[5,6],...]
a = a[(a[:,i] < 5)]**

if your condition is multicolumn based, then you can make a new array applying the conditions on the columns. Then you can just compare the new array with value 5(according to my assumption) to get indexes and follow above codes.
Note that, whatever i have written in (), returns the index array.