# In Python / numpy, how do I unravel / split an array according to its first column, which is an index?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split, indexing

This question is closely related to [How to split an array according to a condition in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662458/how-to-split-an-array-according-to-a-condition-in-numpy) but I am looking for a more general way to split an array given an unknown number of indices:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.arange(10,40).reshape(10,3)
b=np.array([[1],[1],[1],[2],[2],[3],[3],[4],[4],[5]])
c=np.hstack((b,a))

array([[ 1, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 1, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 1, 16, 17, 18],
       [ 2, 19, 20, 21],
       [ 2, 22, 23, 24],
       [ 3, 25, 26, 27],
       [ 3, 28, 29, 30],
       [ 4, 31, 32, 33],
       [ 4, 34, 35, 36],
       [ 5, 37, 38, 39]])
```

I'd like to split this up into a 1x2x2 array according to the first column, thus:

```
array([[[ 1, 10, 11, 12],
        [ 1, 13, 14, 15],
        [ 1, 16, 17, 18]],

       [[ 2, 19, 20, 21],
        [ 2, 22, 23, 24]],

       [[ 3, 25, 26, 27],
        [ 3, 28, 29, 30]],

       [[ 4, 31, 32, 33],
        [ 4, 34, 35, 36]],

       [[ 5, 37, 38, 39]]])
```

I am new to Python, so thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: As an aside, consider using the [Pandas library](http://pandas.pydata.org/) if you can. It has lots of handy built-in functions for this sort of thing. In this case, you could easily create a [`pandas.DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#dataframe) from your data, set the first column as an index, or use the [`groupby` function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html) to group by common first-column values.

Comment: @EMS groupby in pandas would work but setting the first colunm to index would raise a uniqueness error.  panels are also no good since they expect square data.

Comment: Your expected output is not actually possible as an array of integers in numpy, since it does not have a uniform shape.  In practice, it's legal because it will effectively become a list (numpy object array) of five numpy arrays.

Comment: @PhilCooper newer versions of Pandas allow indexes with duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pure python you can do it using `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint ([list(g) for k, g in groupby(c, key=itemgetter(0))])
[[array([ 1, 10, 11, 12]), array([ 1, 13, 14, 15]), array([ 1, 16, 17, 18])],
 [array([ 2, 19, 20, 21]), array([ 2, 22, 23, 24])],
 [array([ 3, 25, 26, 27]), array([ 3, 28, 29, 30])],
 [array([ 4, 31, 32, 33]), array([ 4, 34, 35, 36])],
 [array([ 5, 37, 38, 39])]]
```

Using `NumPy`:

```
>>> e, inds = np.unique(c[:,0], return_index=True)
>>> np.split(c, inds)[1:]
[array([[ 1, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 1, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 1, 16, 17, 18]]),
 array([[ 2, 19, 20, 21],
       [ 2, 22, 23, 24]]),
 array([[ 3, 25, 26, 27],
       [ 3, 28, 29, 30]]),
 array([[ 4, 31, 32, 33],
       [ 4, 34, 35, 36]]),
 array([[ 5, 37, 38, 39]])]
```

Comment: Thank you @Ashwini Chaudhary - but I'm not sure this is exactly what I was looking for.  The arrays for 1:5 are still all grouped together:  I'd like 5 separate groups of arrays.  Is this possible?  Thank you.

Comment: @user2974839 I don't understand, the returned list is a list of lists with five separate groups.

Comment: @user2974839 Also check my NumPy solution.

Comment: Aha, I like your Numpy solution.  Thanks!

Comment: @askewchan oops. not strange, just spaced it out. fixed it