# Acces numpy array with potentially out of bounds index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have indices `index` that are potentially out of bounds for array `arr`.

```
IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

How can I access just the valid indices `index_valid` of `arr` and get the invalid indices `index_invalid` as another variable?

Example:

```
arr = np.array([1,2,3])
index = np.array([1,2,3])

if index.min() >= len(arr):
    index_valid = np.array([])
    index_invalid = index
    arr_desired = np.array([])
else:
    index_valid = np.array([i for i in index if i<len(arr)])
    index_invalid = np.array([i for i in index if i>=len(arr)])
    arr_desired = arr[index_valid]
```

Important: The solution must be robust to cases where all indices in `index` are not in `arr`.
Furthermore I am looking for a `numpy` like solution without listcomps and if possible without `if` statements.

Comment: test the index against the array shape.

Comment: IIUC: `index_valid = index[index < len(arr)]` ?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny ah thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. Post it as answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @gustavz - I think it's answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7662458/14277722) but doesn't feel like a duplicate.

Comment: yes partly, but if you add `index_invalid = index[index >= len(arr)]; arr_desired = arr[index_valid]` it's a complete answer to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the extended comment of @Michael Szczesny as answer:

```
index_valid = index[index < len(arr)]
index_invalid = index[index >= len(arr)]
arr_desired = arr[index_valid]
```